# Import *.LAS Files

Tags: import

What is the best way to import *.LAS files?

I've found lots of ways, but they're all pretty dated;)

I've confirmed that my *.LAS files import correctly in Revit.

Answer (score 1):

When I played around with Lidar data previously I wrote myself this little hint sheet. Might help you out:

- Open LAS files using 3DEM
- Export via File

  - / Save Map Image
  - / Export GeoTIFF DEM
- Use BlenderGIS

  - File / Import / Georeferenced Raster
  - Use options in bottom left of import window. Import first On Plane using Map - Image from 3DEM
  - Then import again As DEM / Use Existing Mesh. Turn off subsurf option (use Mesh). Seems to give best results.
  - May crash/fail multiple times, so persevere with options a bit.

Comment: Is 3DEM running on GNU/Linux? I forgot to say which platform I was running.

Answer (score 1):

Use CloudCompare to convert to a PLY and import that in Blender w built-in ply importer